# Illegal pattern component: p while dealing with DATE

Tags: java, jodatime

Error :

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: p
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.parsePatternTo(DateTimeFormat.java:559)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.createFormatterForPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:682)
>       at org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern(DateTimeFormat.java:170)
>       at com.myjavapapers.time.JodaTimeDemo.getDate(JodaTimeDemo.java:29)
>       at com.myjavapapers.time.JodaTimeDemo.main(JodaTimeDemo.java:21)

```
System.out.println(getDate("09/16/14 1:07 PM", "MM/dd/yy hh:mm pm"));


public static Date getDate(final String dateTimeS, final String format) {
    if (StringUtils.isEmpty(dateTimeS)) {
        return null;
    }
    DateTimeFormatter fmt   = DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format);
    DateTime dateTime       = fmt.parseDateTime(dateTimeS);

    return dateTime.toDate();
}
```

Comment: I don't know `Joda` but my guess is for wrong format ... try to remove `" pm"`

Comment: What is your Java and JodaTime version?

Answer (score 2):

The error tells you that `p` is not an allowed character for the parser. You have to use the component `a` to parse the AM/PM string. That should work:

```
getDate("09/16/14 1:07 PM", "MM/dd/yy hh:mm a")
```

Take a look at the [documentation](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) for more explanation.

Comment: even I changed it to a .. it is saying 'a' is not allowed .

Comment: Your code (with `a` instead of `pm`) works by me with Joda-Time 2.4 and Java 7.